# Testing SpringBatch job via independent JUnit 5 based test

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch, spring-boot-test

My Spring Boot application invoking a sample Spring Batch job is configured as below:

**MainApplication.java**:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MainApplication {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            
        new SpringApplicationBuilder(MainApplication.class).web(WebApplicationType.NONE).run(args);
    }

}
```

**AggregateItemJobConfiguration.java**:

```
@Slf4j
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class AggregateItemJobConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;
/*
    @Bean
       public EmbeddedDatabase dataSource() {
          return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder().build();
       }
    
    @Bean
       public JobRepositoryFactoryBean myJobRepository(DataSource dataSource) {
          JobRepositoryFactoryBean jobRepositoryFactoryBean = new JobRepositoryFactoryBean();
          jobRepositoryFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
           return jobRepositoryFactoryBean;
      }
*/  
    
    @Bean
    public Job job() throws Exception {
        return this.jobBuilderFactory
                .get("multilineJob")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .flow(step())
                .end()
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step step() throws Exception {
        return this.stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
                .<Trade, Trade>chunk(1)
                .reader(reader())
                .writer(writer())
                .processor(processor())
                .build();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public ItemProcessor<Trade, Trade> processor() {
        return new ItemProcessor<Trade, Trade>() {

            @Override
            public Trade process(Trade item) throws Exception {
                log.info("In processor: "+item.getCustomer());
                item.setProcessed(true);
                return item;
            }
        };
    }
    
    
    
    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public FlatFileItemWriter<Trade> writer(
            ) {
        return new FlatFileItemWriterBuilder<Trade>()
                .name("tradeWriter")
                .resource(new FileSystemResource("target/test-outputs/20070122.testStream.multilineStep.txt"))
                .lineAggregator(new PassThroughLineAggregator<Trade>())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public ItemReader<Trade> reader() {
        AggregateItemReader<Trade> aggregateItemReader = new AggregateItemReader<>();
        aggregateItemReader.setItemReader(fileItemReader());
        
        return new DequeueItemReader<>(aggregateItemReader);
    }

    
    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public FlatFileItemReader<AggregateItem<Trade>> fileItemReader(
     
            ) {

        return new FlatFileItemReaderBuilder<AggregateItem<Trade>>()
                .name("tradeFileItemReader")
                .resource(new ClassPathResource("data/20070122.teststream.multilineStep.txt"))
                .linesToSkip(0)
                .lineTokenizer(fixedFileDescriptor())
                .fieldSetMapper(fieldSetMapper())
                .build();
    }
    

    

    
    @Bean
    public AggregateItemFieldSetMapper<Trade> fieldSetMapper() {
        AggregateItemFieldSetMapper<Trade> fieldSetMapper = new AggregateItemFieldSetMapper<>();
        fieldSetMapper.setDelegate(new TradeFieldSetMapper());
        return fieldSetMapper;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    @Bean
    public PatternMatchingCompositeLineTokenizer fixedFileDescriptor() {

        PatternMatchingCompositeLineTokenizer lineTokenizer = new PatternMatchingCompositeLineTokenizer();

        Map<String, LineTokenizer> tokenizers = new HashMap<String, LineTokenizer>() {
            
            {
                put("BEGIN*", beginRecordTokenizer());
                put("END*", endRecordTokenizer());
                put("*", tradeRecordTokenizer());
            }
        };

        lineTokenizer.setTokenizers(tokenizers);
        return lineTokenizer;

    }

    @Bean
    public FixedLengthTokenizer beginRecordTokenizer() {
        FixedLengthTokenizer tokenizer = new FixedLengthTokenizer();
        tokenizer.setColumns(new Range[] { new Range(1, 5) });
        return tokenizer;
    }

    @Bean
    public FixedLengthTokenizer endRecordTokenizer() {
        FixedLengthTokenizer tokenizer = new FixedLengthTokenizer();
        tokenizer.setColumns(new Range[] { new Range(1, 3) });
        return tokenizer;
    }

    @Bean
    public FixedLengthTokenizer tradeRecordTokenizer() {
        FixedLengthTokenizer tokenizer = new FixedLengthTokenizer();
        tokenizer.setNames(new String[] { "ISIN", "Quantity", "Price", "Customer" });
        tokenizer.setColumns(new Range[] { 
                new Range(1, 12), 
                new Range(13, 15), 
                new Range(16, 20), 
                new Range(21, 29) });
        return tokenizer;
    }

}
```

When run in an IDE as a Spring Boot application, the run is successful (after I've added the h2 dependency in **pom.xml**:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

without which (for some reason) it doesn't work:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class


Action:

Consider the following:
    If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or Derby), please put it on the classpath.
    If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (no profiles are currently active).
```

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
[32m :: Spring Boot :: [39m             [2m (v2.7.14)[0;39m

[2m2023-08-22 15:55:59.664[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m18040[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mc.p.g.f.d.d.a.provider.MainApplication  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Starting MainApplication using Java 11.0.16.1 on VXABZS4H9100738 with PID 18040 (C:\code\STS\return-data-processor\target\classes started by x266345 in C:\code\STS\return-data-processor)
[2m2023-08-22 15:55:59.668[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m18040[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mc.p.g.f.d.d.a.provider.MainApplication  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
[2m2023-08-22 15:56:00.641[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m18040[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mfaultConfiguringBeanFactoryPostProcessor[0;39m [2m:[0;39m No bean named 'errorChannel' has been explicitly defined. Therefore, a default PublishSubscribeChannel will be created.
[2m2023-08-22 15:56:00.664[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m18040[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mfaultConfiguringBeanFactoryPostProcessor[0;39m [2m:[0;39m No bean named 'integrationHeaderChannelRegistry' has been explicitly defined. Therefore, a default DefaultHeaderChannelRegistry will be created.
[2m2023-08-22 15:56:01.201[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m18040[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mcom.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HikariPool-1 - Starting...
[2m2023-08-22 15:56:01.617[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m18040[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mcom.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
[2m2023-08-22 15:56:01.949[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m18040[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.s.b.c.r.s.JobRepositoryFactoryBean    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m No database type set, using meta data indicating: H2
[2m2023-08-22 15:56:01.976[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m18040[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher     [0;39m [2m:[0;39m No TaskExecutor has been set, defaulting to synchronous executor.
[2m2023-08-22 15:56:02.310[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m18040[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Adding {logging-channel-adapter:_org.springframework.integration.errorLogger} as a subscriber to the 'errorChannel' channel
[2m2023-08-22 15:56:02.310[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m18040[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.s.i.channel.PublishSubscribeChannel   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Channel 'application.errorChannel' has 1 subscriber(s).
[2m2023-08-22 15:56:02.311[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m18040[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m started bean '_org.springframework.integration.errorLogger'
[2m2023-08-22 15:56:02.322[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m18040[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mc.p.g.f.d.d.a.provider.MainApplication  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Started MainApplication in 3.163 seconds (JVM running for 8.508)
[2m2023-08-22 15:56:02.324[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m18040[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.s.b.a.b.JobLauncherApplicationRunner  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Running default command line with: []
[2m2023-08-22 15:56:02.401[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m18040[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher     [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Job: [FlowJob: [name=multilineJob]] launched with the following parameters: [{run.id=1}]
[2m2023-08-22 15:56:02.447[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m18040[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.s.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Executing step: [step1]
[2m2023-08-22 15:56:02.509[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m18040[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mc.p.g.f.d.d.a.p.DequeueItemReader       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Is Queue empty: true
[2m2023-08-22 15:56:02.524[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m18040[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mc.p.g.f.d.d.a.p.DequeueItemReader       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Aggregated read size: 2
[2m2023-08-22 15:56:02.524[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m18040[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mc.p.g.f.d.d.a.p.DequeueItemReader       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Queue size: 2
[2m2023-08-22 15:56:02.528[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m18040[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36m.f.d.d.a.p.AggregateItemJobConfiguration[0;39m [2m:[0;39m In processor: customer1
[2m2023-08-22 15:56:02.533[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m18040[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mc.p.g.f.d.d.a.p.DequeueItemReader       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Is Queue empty: false
[2m2023-08-22 15:56:02.533[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m18040[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mc.p.g.f.d.d.a.p.DequeueItemReader       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Queue size: 1
[2m2023-08-22 15:56:02.533[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m18040[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36m.f.d.d.a.p.AggregateItemJobConfiguration[0;39m [2m:[0;39m In processor: customer2
[2m2023-08-22 15:56:02.535[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m18040[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mc.p.g.f.d.d.a.p.DequeueItemReader       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Is Queue empty: true
[2m2023-08-22 15:56:02.536[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m18040[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mc.p.g.f.d.d.a.p.DequeueItemReader       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Aggregated read size: 3
[2m2023-08-22 15:56:02.536[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m18040[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mc.p.g.f.d.d.a.p.DequeueItemReader       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Queue size: 3
[2m2023-08-22 15:56:02.536[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m18040[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36m.f.d.d.a.p.AggregateItemJobConfiguration[0;39m [2m:[0;39m In processor: customer2
[2m2023-08-22 15:56:02.538[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m18040[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mc.p.g.f.d.d.a.p.DequeueItemReader       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Is Queue empty: false
[2m2023-08-22 15:56:02.538[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m18040[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mc.p.g.f.d.d.a.p.DequeueItemReader       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Queue size: 2
[2m2023-08-22 15:56:02.538[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m18040[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36m.f.d.d.a.p.AggregateItemJobConfiguration[0;39m [2m:[0;39m In processor: customer3
[2m2023-08-22 15:56:02.540[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m18040[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mc.p.g.f.d.d.a.p.DequeueItemReader       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Is Queue empty: false
[2m2023-08-22 15:56:02.540[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m18040[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mc.p.g.f.d.d.a.p.DequeueItemReader       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Queue size: 1
[2m2023-08-22 15:56:02.540[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m18040[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36m.f.d.d.a.p.AggregateItemJobConfiguration[0;39m [2m:[0;39m In processor: customer4
[2m2023-08-22 15:56:02.543[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m18040[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mc.p.g.f.d.d.a.p.DequeueItemReader       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Is Queue empty: true
[2m2023-08-22 15:56:02.543[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m18040[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mc.p.g.f.d.d.a.p.DequeueItemReader       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Queue size: 0
[2m2023-08-22 15:56:02.545[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m18040[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.s.batch.core.step.AbstractStep        [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Step: [step1] executed in 98ms
[2m2023-08-22 15:56:02.552[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m18040[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher     [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Job: [FlowJob: [name=multilineJob]] completed with the following parameters: [{run.id=1}] and the following status: [COMPLETED] in 124ms
[2m2023-08-22 15:56:02.559[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m18040[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ionShutdownHook][0;39m [36mo.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Removing {logging-channel-adapter:_org.springframework.integration.errorLogger} as a subscriber to the 'errorChannel' channel
[2m2023-08-22 15:56:02.561[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m18040[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ionShutdownHook][0;39m [36mo.s.i.channel.PublishSubscribeChannel   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Channel 'application.errorChannel' has 0 subscriber(s).
[2m2023-08-22 15:56:02.561[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m18040[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ionShutdownHook][0;39m [36mo.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m stopped bean '_org.springframework.integration.errorLogger'
[2m2023-08-22 15:56:02.583[0;39m [33m WARN[0;39m [35m18040[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ionShutdownHook][0;39m [36mo.s.b.f.support.DisposableBeanAdapter   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Custom destroy method 'close' on bean with name 'reader' threw an exception: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ScopeNotActiveException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.fileItemReader': Scope 'step' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No context holder available for step scope
[2m2023-08-22 15:56:02.583[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m18040[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ionShutdownHook][0;39m [36mcom.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
[2m2023-08-22 15:56:02.591[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m18040[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ionShutdownHook][0;39m [36mcom.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
```

I want to restructure that batch application **to be invoked by** a corresponding JUnit 5-based **test** (will have separate tests for other batch applications).  Something like this:

**AggregateItemJobTest.java**

```
@Slf4j
@SpringBatchTest
@SpringJUnitConfig(AggregateItemJobConfiguration.class)
class AggregateItemJobTest {

    @Autowired
    private JobLauncherTestUtils jobLauncherTestUtils;

    @Autowired
    private JobRepositoryTestUtils jobRepositoryTestUtils;

    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Autowired
    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }
    
    @AfterEach
    public void cleanUp() {
        jobRepositoryTestUtils.removeJobExecutions();
    }
    
    @Autowired
    public JobLauncher jobLauncher ;

    @Test
    void testJob() throws Exception {
        log.info("In test");
        JobExecution jobExecution = jobLauncherTestUtils.launchJob();
    }

}
```

running which however results in the following:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ScopeNotActiveException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.fileItemReader': Scope 'step' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No context holder available for step scope
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:383)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
..........
    at 
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestReference.run(JUnit5TestReference.java:98)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:529)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:756)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:452)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'jobRepositoryTestUtils': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setDataSource' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'javax.sql.DataSource' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.resolveMethodArguments(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:774)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:727)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1431)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:619)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:955)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:921)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:127)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:60)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:276)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:244)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:141)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:90)
    ... 71 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'javax.sql.DataSource' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1801)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1357)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1311)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.resolveMethodArguments(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:766)
    ... 90 common frames omitted
16:05:35.641 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDirtiesContextTestExecutionListener - After test class: context [DefaultTestContext@409c54f testClass = AggregateItemJobTest, testInstance = [null], testMethod = [null], testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration = [MergedContextConfiguration@3e74829 testClass = AggregateItemJobTest, locations = '{}', classes = '{class com.pru.globalpayments.feeds.downstream.dailycashreport.acquire.provider.AggregateItemJobConfiguration}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{}', contextCustomizers = set[org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@44be0077, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@51a9ad5e, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.actuate.metrics.MetricsExportContextCustomizerFactory$DisableMetricExportContextCustomizer@42b3b079, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizerFactory$Customizer@24c4ddae, org.springframework.batch.test.context.BatchTestContextCustomizer@4a3631f8], contextLoader = 'org.springframework.test.context.support.DelegatingSmartContextLoader', parent = [null]], attributes = map['org.springframework.test.context.event.ApplicationEventsTestExecutionListener.recordApplicationEvents' -> false]], class annotated with @DirtiesContext [false] with mode [null].
```

An attempt to add a data source separately, per suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61105968/how-to-successfullky-load-the-joblaunchertestutils-class-for-a-spring-task-for-a), breaks the previously running `MainApplication.java` execution. Please see more explanations along with the associated stack trace down in the comments.

Could someone please point me to a complete working (minimal, but full) sample of running Spring Batch job from JUnit 5 test.

The repo with the codebase described above can be found here: https://github.com/excelsiorsoft/spring-batch-aggregation-poc

Comment: Since H2 is in the classpath, you should not have that error message from Spring Boot. `An attempt to add a data source separately, per suggestions here, breaks the previously running MainApplication.java execution.` How is that? Are you referring to the `APPLICATION FAILED TO START` message below? Based on the logs you shared , the app seems to run correctly. I can provide a sample, but I want to first understand how providing a datasource breaks the main app.

Comment: Note a `DataSourceConfig` class in the main tree.  It's supposed to be annotated with @Configuration, per that suggestion link I referred to above but doing so produces the following trace now when doing Run as Spring Boot App in the IDE: https://github.com/sleyzerzon/return-data-processor/blob/main/trace.txt.  APPLICATION FAILED TO START canned one was prior to me adding the h2 to pom.xml, after which the invocation via IDE's "Run as SB App", but not as test, started to work.  Hope that makes sense.

Comment: I added an answer with an example. It should help. Please don't duplicate questions to avoid duplicate efforts: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76956597.

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to reproduce the issue you mentioned. With H2 in the classpath, Spring Boot will create an embedded database, which will be used by Spring Batch automatically.

> Could someone please point me to a complete working (minimal, but full) sample of running Spring Batch job from JUnit 5 test.

Here is a minimal complete example based on a project generated from start.spring.io with Spring Batch and H2 dependencies:

https://start.spring.io/#!type=maven-project&language=java&platformVersion=2.7.15&packaging=jar&jvmVersion=1.8&groupId=com.example&artifactId=demo&name=demo&description=Demo%20project%20for%20Spring%20Boot&packageName=com.example.demo&dependencies=batch,h2

The main class in `src/main/java/com/example/demo/DemoApplication.java`:

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.EnableBatchProcessing;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.JobBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.repeat.RepeatStatus;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

@EnableBatchProcessing
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public Job job(JobBuilderFactory jobs, StepBuilderFactory steps) {
        return jobs.get("job")
                .start(steps.get("step")
                        .tasklet((contribution, chunkContext) -> {
                            System.out.println("hello world");
                            return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
                        })
                        .build())
                .build();
    }

}
```

The test in `src/test/java/com/example/demo/DemoApplicationTests.java`:

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import org.springframework.batch.core.ExitStatus;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobExecution;
import org.springframework.batch.test.JobLauncherTestUtils;
import org.springframework.batch.test.context.SpringBatchTest;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;

@SpringBatchTest
@SpringBootTest
class DemoApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    private JobLauncherTestUtils jobLauncherTestUtils;

    @Test
    void contextLoads() throws Exception {
        //when
        JobExecution jobExecution = jobLauncherTestUtils.launchJob();

        // then
        Assertions.assertEquals(ExitStatus.COMPLETED, jobExecution.getExitStatus());
    }

}
```

The pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.15</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-batch-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

The `application.properties` file is empty.

With that in place, the main app as well as the test pass without any issue.